# Vaadin 8: Dynamically turn on and off @Push to use @Push with cookies

Tags: cookies, push, vaadin8

In my application (Vaadin.8.6.3, Tomcat 9 and Maven 3) I need to set cookies which works well unless I use @Push. I need @Push only for one progress window implemented as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53814542/vaadin-8-how-to-show-progressbar-window-before-navigating-to-other-view-with-lo).

I read that it is possible to turn @Push on and off using e.g.

`getUI().getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC);`

I tried several ways and places in the code to turn @Push on and off, but nothing worked.

One example:

```
 @Push(PushMode.DISABLED)
public class MyUI extends UI {
```

Since I have more than one place in the code where I do cookies handling, I thought the best is to disable @Push in the UI class and turn it on when I run the background thread.

With a button click I start the runnable and in the runnable I turn on the @Push mode:

```
    class Loader implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            getUI().access(() -> {
                getUI().getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC);
                getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("scandataview/" + name);
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no error but nothing happens, i.e. the data I want to load are never loaded and the progress window stays forever.

My questions:

Is it possible to just turn on @Push to show the progress window while loading long data and turn it off after loading?

If yes, where in the code should I turn on/off the @Push?

If you need more information please let me know. I would be very glad for your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need Push only in one place and for some reason have described complications I recommend the following.

Set the push mode to manual i.e. `@Push(PushMode.MANUAL)`

And then modify the code as follows, i.e. perform manual push instead of relying automatic.

```
class Loader implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            getUI().access(() -> {
                getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("scandataview/" + name);
                getUI().push();
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above use of `access()` can be further improved according information provided in this question: [Access method from current UI in Vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553345/access-method-from-current-ui-in-vaadin/52553836#52553836)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the getUI problem! I added a ui variabe that is set in the constructor as ui = UI.getCurrent(); Then your piece of code did work. However, by setting @Push(PushMode.MANUAL) the Push is enabled and the cookie setting does not work! Now, I am using no Push annotation and then I can turn on and off the push with UI.getCurrent().getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.MANUAL); or PushMode.DISABLED. Since turning on and off needs time I need to implement waiting loops (dirty workarounds). How do I know when the PushMode has changed?